# Fetching last good values based on the condition with SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, plsqldeveloper

I need a query on the below table with the output as mentioned below

I have the columns `Timestamp, A, B, C, D`
And, the sample data as follows

```
 Timestamp       A   B    C   D
------------------------------
20-7-2013:2:15   1  360   1  -5
20-7-2013:7:15   2  360   E  -3
21-7-2013:9:15   N  360   E  -6
21-7-2013:10:15  N  360   E  -8
22-7-2013:11:15  N  360   E  -7
```

Firstly, I need to check the Column `A` last record value is `(NULL or E or -ve)` values, if either of these three are yes, then i need to get the last good value date( in the case of A column the output should be "20-7-2013:7:15") depend on the condition(between 0 to 360, >0, -5 to +5 for each column). The same has to be done for the columns A to Z. And the Final output should be

```
ColumnName      Time
------------------------- 
    A      20-7-2013:7:15
```

**Update**: For column A the output should be : 20-7-2013:7:15 ( as it is immediate good value from last NULL); column B can be ignored as the last value is 360 and it satisfy the condition; for Column C the output should be: 20-7-2013:2:15 as the condition is last good value before E error, and the column D output should be 20-7-2013:7:15  as it is satisfying the condition ( value between -5 and +5)... Please help

Comment: As you said `The same has to be done for the columns A to Z. And the Final output should be`, what same has to be done?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i mean, the way i get the output for column A with the conditions and the same i need to get for the remaining columns as well in output

Comment: Can you post a Query which you have tried so far

Comment: I am sorry, still i haven't build the query yet..trying.. Greatly appreciate if you can help on this

Comment: You mentioned in your post that `Column A last record value` that means Oldest record or newest record?

Comment: It is Newest record, then we need to check the oldest record for the last good values with the conditions for each column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the different columns have different criteria for "good value", I would just have a query for each column in turn, and `UNION` them together

e.g.

```
SELECT TOP 1 'A' AS ColumnName, Timestamp AS [Time] FROM <table>
WHERE A IS NOT NULL AND ISNUMERIC(A) = 1 AND A >= 0
ORDER BY Timestamp DESC
UNION
SELECT TOP 1 'B', Timestamp FROM <table>
WHERE B IS NOT NULL AND ISNUMERIC(B) = 1 AND B BETWEEN 0 AND 360 
ORDER BY Timestamp DESC
UNION
...
```

**Update:**
From the comments below, I think I understand what is going on here.
It sounds like each column has some conditions to check, and then also should be excluded if the final date satisfies the condition. I suggest an outer query around the `UNION` of column queries to remove the cases where the last value satisfies.

**Update 2**

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT TOP 1 'A' AS ColumnName, Timestamp AS [Time] FROM <table>
    WHERE A IS NOT NULL AND ISNUMERIC(A) = 1 AND A BETWEEN 0 AND 360
    ORDER BY Timestamp DESC
    UNION
    SELECT TOP 1 'B', Timestamp FROM <table>
    WHERE B IS NOT NULL AND ISNUMERIC(B) = 1 AND B > 0
    ORDER BY Timestamp DESC
    UNION
    SELECT TOP 1 'C', Timestamp FROM <table>
    WHERE C IS NOT NULL AND ISNUMERIC(C) = 1 AND C BETWEEN -5 AND 5
    ORDER BY Timestamp DESC
    UNION
    SELECT TOP 1 'D', Timestamp FROM <table>
    WHERE D IS NOT NULL AND ISNUMERIC(D) = 1 AND D BETWEEN -5 AND 5
    ORDER BY Timestamp DESC
) Cols
WHERE [Time] < ( SELECT TOP 1 Timestamp FROM <table> ORDER BY Timestamp DESC )
```

Comment: Can you please help me to get the exact output what i want for 1 column A with the condition satisfied( either is NULL or E or negative value) then fetch the good value date with the condtion( either in between 0 to 360 or >0 or -5 to +5)?..  i will replicate for all the columns with union... i am not getting the output from the above query for Columns A

Comment: Are those three conditions meant for the same column? or are there conditions across multiple columns for getting the right A? >0 is implied in between 0 and 360, and between -5 and 5 contradicts that half the time

Comment: Hmm, conditions apply for each respective column, if column A values falls in 0 to 360 we need to use this condition, if column B falls in negative values then we need to use negative conditions.

Comment: @RJ1990: If the last row value for column is not falls in between " NULL or E or negative value), if negative we have the condition say it should be in between -5 to +5, if the last value for the column satisfied the above conditions then only it should display the output, if these 3 conditions are not satisfied output should be ignored for that column. Please help

Comment: @Reyaz : Now Check [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2eae2/1) . If it is not an answer then please give some detail and regular terms instead of your specific term like `last row value for column is not falls in between`

Comment: @Roms, i did not got the expected output, sorry if i am not clear, Let me explain clearly as per the above mentioned table in my question. I need output as the column name and with the date(last good values date, this value should satisfy the conditions like the value should be 0 to 360). Now we are doing maunally by going to the last value of each column( for example, Column A last value is NULL, if the last value is null or Error or negative value) then we need to go top for the last good value, in case of A columns the last good value is "2"(0 to 360) with the time stamp "20-7-2013:7:15"

Comment: for column A the last good value that satisfy the condition in between 0 to 360 is "2" so we need to get the date for that value, for column B the last good value is 360 with the date "22-7-2013:4:15" in this case i dont need the output for column B as it has recorded the good value latest which it satisfy the condition ( value in between 0 to 360) like this we have to get the last good value date with the conditions statisfy for each coloum.. Hope this helps

Comment: @Caleth: thanks for your query, but the table values are dynamic, for example, take column A, if the last recorded value is not satisfying the condition(value should be between 0 to 360) then it has to search going on top to get the previous last good value... could you please help me

Comment: Yes, the SELECT TOP 1 ... WHERE _condition_ ORDER BY Timestamp should return the latest good value for that column, and then the outer query removes those which are the final row

Comment: i have modified the output in my question. Could you please help me to write exact query to give the output as i mentioned in the question. And the values are dynamic in table. now it is "1" value in one cell after 1 day it can change to some other value say -58. It would be great if you can help me on this till i get the exact output. Thank you very  much

Comment: can i get the output for last 7 or customized dates?

Comment: You can change the TOP 1 to be TOP 7 and it will give you the 7 newest entries that satisfy the conditions